# Working with arrays to produce a single array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that can have many values at any given point, what I would like to accomplish is to combine all the array indexes and form one index with my final value. Merge other values that are the same

Say I have the array result below

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [component] => sodium chloride
            [generic_results] => Average:=99.20%
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [component] => sodium chloride
            [generic_results] => RSD:=0.54%
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [component] => sodium chloride
            [generic_results] => n:=3
        )

)
```

What I would like is something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [component] => sodium chloride
            [generic_results] => Average:=99.20%,RSD:=0.54%, n:=3
        )
)
```

I have tried array unique but its not working.

Example code generating the results:

```
   $arr=array(
            (object) array(
                'component'=>'sodium chloride',
                 'generic_results'=>'Average:=99'
            ),
            (object) array(
                'component'=>'sodium chloride',
                 'generic_results'=>'RSD:=0.54'
            ),
            (object) array(
                'component'=>'sodium chloride',
                 'generic_results'=>'n:=3'
            )
        );      

        print('<pre>');
        print_r($arr); 
        print('</pre>');
```

Any Suggestions for this problem?

Comment: Unique does not work because each record is unique, only parts of the record are the same. You have to loop over your array and remember which "component" entries you have seen using a temporary array and a function like `in_array()` and adding the different results to other variables in order to do the mean calculation etc.

Comment: Refining your question: 1) Will you **always** receive an array of stdClass Objects, with **always** two properties `[component]` and `[generic_results]`, even if the size of this array may varies? 2) Is `[generic_results]` the **only** field that varies? 3) If (2) is **no**, would be what you need is to concatenate `[generic_results]` for every time `[component]` matches?

Comment: Yes there will always be two properties no matter what and only generic result will always vary

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$new = array();
foreach ($array as $obj){
    // By setting the key you guarantee it being unique
    $new[$obj->component][$obj->generic_results] = $obj->generic_results;
}

$new2 = array();
foreach ($new as $comp=>$arr){
    $new2['component'][$comp] = implode(',',$arr);
}
```

This will return an array but you can (although its not always sufficient) then use json_decode(json_encode($new2), false) to convert it to the object. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is what. The other thing I want component on its own even if it is used as the key

Comment: Sorry I don't understand

Comment: This is what I wanted. The other thing I want component on its own even if it is used as the key is the component, something like [component]=>sodium chloride  then [sodium chloride]=>......blah blah

Comment: See my updated answer - I believe that is what you're after?

Comment: Your answer gives me this

Comment: Array ( [component] => Array ( [sodium chloride] => Average:=99.20%,RSD:=0.54%,n:=3 ) )

Comment: What I am after is this

Comment: Array ( [component] =>Sodium chloride Array ( [generic_results] => Average:=99.20%,RSD:=0.54%,n:=3 ) )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89707/discussion-between-alphy-and-ukuser32).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/array-reduce), which iterates over an array to combine all elements with a given callback function:

```
$result = array_reduce($arr, function($result, $item) {
    if ($result === null) {

        // initialize with first item
        return [$item];
    }

    // add generic_results of current item to result
    $result[0]->generic_results .= ',' . $item->generic_results;
    return $result;
    }
);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/KBUBl

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, how can i make the same work if i have say the same array, but now the component varies

Comment: Depends what the desired output is